# UI-layout for angular 2

Tags: angular

We have been using this ui-layout component(http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-layout/) with angular 1.  We are moving to angular 2 now and I wanna know of there is an equivalent component for angular 2 Or something better than this.I am particularly looking for the splitter which can be moved to split the screen as per user's wish. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/) I suppose

Comment: is it resizable? I went to demos and it looks static.

Comment: I just realized that flxe-layout is very similar to bootstrap.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599396/flexbox-vs-twitter-bootstrap-or-similar-framework. I am already using bootstrap. I just need a vertical resizable , movable UI splitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

angular-split looks quite promising and powerful (https://bertrandg.github.io/angular-split) and should hopefully play nicely with other ui components. I've just started testing it for a project.

Comment: That's what we ended up using :-). Thank you for answering. I hope it will be helpful for someone else in future.